Object stays undefined after OnInit that's supposed to define it
I have a parent component that contains a massive of objects:
export const myWalls: MyWall[] = [
  {
    sign: 'COTTON CANDY',
    photo1: 'assets\\walls.jpg',
    photo2: 'assets\\1.jpg',
    photo3: 'assets\\2.jpg',
    id:1,
    mySong: [
      {
        name: 'firstsong',
        cover: 'assets\\1.jpg',
        song: 'assets\\audio\\11.mp3',
      },
      {
        name: 'secondsong',
        cover: 'assets\\1.jpg',
        song: 'assets\\audio\\12.mp3',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    sign: 'NEON',
    photo1: 'assets\\3.jpg',
    photo2: 'assets\\4.jpg',
    photo3: 'assets\\5.jpg',
    id:1,
    mySong: [
      {
        name: 'thirdsong',
        cover: 'assets\\1.jpg',
        song: 'assets\\audio\\11.mp3',
      },
      {
        name: 'fourthsong',
        cover: 'assets\\1.jpg',
        song: 'assets\\audio\\11.mp3',
      },
    ]
  }
]

every object is connected to a certain route by its id field. and by grabbing this id i am supposed to get the rest of the properties of an object. for that i have a constructor in a child component. But even after initialization the object stays undefined and it ruins everything that follows. can anyone please say what could be the problem?
export class FirstInComponent{
  public object?: MyWall;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.object = myWalls[params['id']-1];
      console.log(typeof this.object)
    })
  }

i tried to use OnInit instead of constructor but nothing changes
public object?: MyWall;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.object = myWalls[params['id']-1];
      console.log(typeof this.object)
    })
  }


I think the id field is stored as string. You need to convert the id to number using +
  public object?: MyWall;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      const id: number = +(params?.['id'] || 0);
      this.object = myWalls[id - 1];
      console.log(typeof this.object)
    })
  }



console.log(1+1);

console.log('1'+1);




should also be able to do something like: parseInt(params.id as string);   I'd wrap it in if(params.id) {.... }, too.
